# autocomplete notepad++ for the private libraries

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, notepad++

I am using notepad++ for ruby coding also I am using autocomplete  feature.

but i dint found any plugin to parse the "require " statement and autocomplete from that file options?

any help/suggestion

Comment: Did you know any plugin for auto code formatting like sublime,in Notepad++?

Comment: AFAIK there's no such plugin for Ruby. I think there's only one for Python (which parses the `import`s).